# Passing optional query variables through .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Oh, .htaccess hurts my head.

So, I have a webpage which has a pretty URL of **foo.com/radio/jobs** though actually lives at foo.com/content/directory_jobs.php/?section=radio

I achieve this using an .htaccess line of...

```
RewriteRule ^(radio|tv|magazines|newspapers)/jobs$ /content/directory_jobs.php?section=$1
```

This same page has an optional ?pages= query string - so you can go to **foo.com/radio/jobs?page=2** and see the second page.

The above .htaccess line, however, doesn't add this pages variable: with the result that the underlying PHP script doesn't see a 'pages' variable.

Can I tweak the above .htaccess line to ensure that I do pass a 'pages' variable if it exists? Or do I have to have two .htaccess lines for every page like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the QSA (Query string append) flag

```
RewriteRule ^(radio|tv|magazines|newspapers)/jobs$ /content/directory_jobs.php?section=$1 [QSA]
```

Example;
With QSA flag
/radio/jobs -> /content/directory_jobs.php?section=jobs
/radio/jobs?foo=bar -> /content/directory_jobs.php?section=jobs&foo=bar
/radio/jobs?foo=bar&boo=bosh -> /content/directory_jobs.php?section=jobs&foo=bar&boo=bosh
mod_rewrite will figure out if it needs to add a ? or a $ so for a rewrite rule

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /$1.php [QSA]

/something?foo=bar -> /something.php?foo=bar